# Does Android Jetpack Compose support auto animation?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add an animation to the texts, which will work automatically when the screen is opened

In Android View it can be done easily by just putting this in `OnCreate`

```
 val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.example)
 text.startAnimation(animation)
```

How can the same idea work in Compose ?

What I know in Compose is that the state must be changed to run a particular element animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [side effect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)

```
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    //do something
    onDispose { }
}
```

or:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    //update the value to start the animation
}
```